# Integral power of product of two complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

In Apostol Calculus One, $z=\lvert z \rvert e^{i\theta}$ where $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$ and $\theta = \arg(z)$.

If $z_1z_2\ne0$, $\arg(z_1z_2)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)+2\pi n(z_1,z_2)$ , where$$n(z_1,z_2)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }-\pi<\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)\le+\pi,\\+1&\text{if }-2\pi<\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)\le-\pi;\\-1&\text{if } +\pi<\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)\le+2\pi.\end{cases}$$

Suppose that $z_1=\lvert z_1 \rvert e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2=\lvert z_2 \rvert e^{i\theta_2}$, where $-\pi < \theta_1 \le \pi$, $-\pi < \theta_2 \le \pi$.

If $\Bbb Z$ is regarded as a subset of $\Bbb C$, then $(z_1z_2)^m=z_1^mz_2^me^{2\pi \min(z_1,z_2)}$, where $z_1,z_2 \in \Bbb C$, $m\in \Bbb Z$ and $m\ne0$. Meanwhile, $(z_1z_2)^m=z_1^mz_2^m$, where $z_1,z_2,m$ is the same as above, so $2\pi \min(z_1,z_2)$ must be $0$ , while $n(z_1,z_2)$ may not be $0$ because $-2\pi < \arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2) \le 2\pi$, which really confuses me.

(Sorry for not descirbing the problem in detail last time and being not familiar with MathJax.)

Comment: What is $n(z_1,z_2)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That. is only one choice of argument. a complex number has infinitely many argument branches. For example, for any $\theta_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and complex $z\neq0$, there is a unique $\theta_0<\theta\leq \theta_0 +2\pi$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ call this $\theta=\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z)$. If $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ then $\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z_1z_2)=\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z_1)+\operatorname{arg}_{\theta_0}(z_2)\mod 2\pi$